# unable to clear large amounts of data from memory

Tags: python, memory

I'm loading a lot of data in `python 2.7.15rc1`, which almost fills up the entire memory I have in the computer. I've been trying to delete this from memory by calling `del`, or using `gc` and this was my final solution, moving everything into `main`, since as far as I know, a function should clean up after itself.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(args)
    gc.collect()
    print("sleeping")
    time.sleep(120)
    subprocess.call(["ls"])
```

Unfortunately, what I actually experience is that when I hit `sleep` the used memory remains the same. This is causing me problems, because after this, I want to call `subprocess` which fails, because it can't allocate enough memory (as far as I know, `subprocess` tries to allocate the same amount that is already allocated or something like that).

Does anybody has any idea what is going on here and what I can do about it?

Comment: try to use del gc.garbage[:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Python is garbage-collected language we have no hard guarantees if calling the `del` or using `gc.collect()` will immediately remove entire memory back to main process which would become available for next operations.

As a workaround you can spawn another process from main thread and after finishing it's tasks, kill that process which will make it's memory freed.

```
import multiprocessing

def dfprocessing_func(data):
    # Execute task's code
    return df

p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
df = p.map(dfprocessing_func, [data])[0]
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

Based on [Andrey Nikishaev ~ Why doesn't Python release the memory when I delete a large object?](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Python-release-the-memory-when-I-delete-a-large-object)

Comment: I had to go with this in the end ... Not particularly happy, but at least guaranteed to work.